# How to check if there is at least one case per column in r?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, na

I have a list of dataframes and I need to understand if in each of the dataframe there is one column that is filled by all NA. So I need a function like complete.cases but for columns and that tells me if there is at least one answer per column. How can I do it?

Below a simplified example (probably in here there will be no NA columns, but is just to let you understand):

```
mylist <- list()
for (i in 1:10){
        temp <- data.frame(V1 <- rnorm(10),
                           V2 <- rnorm(10),
                           V3 <- rnorm(10))
        temp[temp<0] <- NA
        mylist[[i]] <- temp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with combination of `sapply`/`lapply` with `colSums`.

```
any_column_with_all_NA <- sapply(mylist, function(x) any(colSums(!is.na(x)) == 0))
```

This would return logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) if any column in the dataframe has all `NA`'s in it.

Comment: Thank you very much! The perfect solution